# What do you call a person who starts learning something before you do?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, someone who started learning and playing badminton five years before you do, under the same instructor. Another example, like a senior person in the same school.

Thanks.

Comment: These pop out of my head -- prexy or school/team senior.

Comment: A *more experienced* player/driver/actor/teacher etc.

Comment: You might also call them *upper-level* or *upper-classmen*

Comment: *Precocious* might fit too, depending on your usage context.

Answer (score 3):

Words like *forerunner, precursor,* and *predecessor* may serve:
• *[forerunner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forerunner#Noun)*, “a runner at the front or ahead”, also    “a forebear, an ancestor, a predecessor” 
• *[precursor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precursor#Noun)*, “That which precurses, a forerunner, a predecessor, an indicator of approaching events”
• *[predecessor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predecessor#Noun)*, “One who precedes; one who has preceded another in any state, position, office, etc.; one whom another follows or comes after, in any office or position”

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:
 
I may have been too hasty in answering the OP's question: A word for someone who has *started learning* before another person. I'm not sure if my suggestions fit the bill, as they describe learners of a certain experience and not someone who began *earlier* in their studies. If the OP would like to confirm whether I have indeed misinterpreted his question, I will delete my answer. Thank you!

To use your example of someone who has been playing badminton for at least five years *compared* to a complete novice or someone at a much lower level we could describe the student or learner (in one word) as being:

- a **skilled** player
- a **trained** player
- a **senior** player (but this could lead to ambiguity, where the word *senior* can be related to age rather than rank or level of expertise).
- a **tutored** player
- a **semi-proficient** player (Yes, it's a compound noun, not really a single word but *proficient* would be inappropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

would you not just call them ***senior***, perhaps ***upperclassman*** as opposed to freshman or sophomore

or ***veteran*** as opposed to novice or a neophyte

or even an [***old hand***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/old+hand?s=t)?

In a vein similar to previously suggested 'predecessor' you can also call them [***antecessor***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antecessor)